# XPath find nodes from text content fails on some nodes, but not on others -- why?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I'm new to XPath, so I've been experimenting with it in the browser. One form of query I've been experimenting with is matching nodes based on text content, for which I've been using variations of the following function:

```
function getDOMNodesFromText = function ( text, parentNode ) {
  if ( !parentNode ) parentNode = document.body;

  return(
    document.evaluate(
      "//*[contains(translate(text(), \"'’\", ''), '" + text.trim().replace(/['’]/g, '') + "')]",
      parentNode,
      null, 
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
      null
    )
  );
}
```

I dropped this function definition in the browser console in a [Grantland article](http://grantland.com/the-triangle/13-observations-from-the-d-league-showcase/), and for the most part, I was able to find nodes as expected. However, there were some nodes where I was never, under any circumstance, able to match any text with this function, or with variations of this function.

An example node is the last text node in a paragraph tag of the form:

```
<p>
  Everyone was buzzing about it. The Thunder under Sam Presti have long had an affection for Lopez; one former Thunder official 
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDqdEiQm2XU" target="_blank">
    revealed to me two years ago
  </a> 
  that the franchise thought seriously about drafting Lopez over Russell Westbrook in 2008. The Thunder were on the verge of acquiring Lopez at a super-cheap price — something like Jeremy Lamb, Grant Jerrett, and Kendrick Perkins’s expiring contract — until the Nets wisely pulled back to further test the market. I’d expect the Thunder to inquire on Lopez again soon.
</p>
```

(It's the eighth paragraph tag in `div.blog-body` - `document.querySelectorAll( '#layout-main .blog-body p' )[8]` for quick grabbing in the console.)

I found several other text nodes in the article where I ran into the same issue -- not being able to select them from their text content using the function above. All examples I found were text nodes, whose parent element contained other nodes (in all cases I found, the unreachable text node followed an `a` tag inside of a `p` tag, however there are counterexamples of this form in the same article). Otherwise I didn't see any commonalities. I tried many different parent nodes, from the `body` to the direct parent, without success. An example from the paragraph tag above:

```
getDOMNodesFromText( "I’d expect the Thunder to inquire on Lopez again soon.", document.body )
```

which returns an empty `XPathResult` object (snapshotLength is 0).

What am I missing?

Comment: You sure those whacky quotes aren't HTML entities?

Comment: Yes, unless I am missing something. You can check by [going to the article](http://grantland.com/the-triangle/13-observations-from-the-d-league-showcase/), and looking at examples such as `document.querySelectorAll( '#layout-main .blog-body p' )[8]`, in the console.